# how to install a new module on owncloud backend server

Tags: php, linux, ldap

i have enabled LDAP with admin GUI .

[image]

When i tried to configure it , i noted the following warning : 
Warning: `The PHP LDAP module is not installed, the backend will not work. Please ask your system administrator to install it.`

Answer (score 0):

**For Ubuntu :**

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5-ldap
```

then:

```
$ sudo service apach2 service
```

**For RedHat**

```
# yum install php-ldap
```

then

```
# service httpd restart
```